# Concurrency in Java - wait for execution to be finished

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I am currently doing some work with Multi-Threading in Java and I'm pretty stuck on a, most likely, simple thing.

I currently have a JButton that, when pressed invokes the method as follows:

```
private void clickTest() throws InterruptedException{
    statOrganizer.incrementHappiness();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Happiness(workspaceHappy));
    t.start();
}
```

and then takes around 10-30 seconds to complete. During this time however, it is still possible to re-click the JButton so that it messes with how the information is displayed.

What I want to do is during the time this particular thread is "alive", disable the button so that it is no longer possible to click it(and thus activate this thread once it's already going). Once the thread is finished, I want to re-enable the button again.

The button code just looks like this

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        try {
                            clickTest();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Generally, when you want to wait for a thread to finish, you should call [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) on it. Altough this will prevent your GUI from updating for the duration of the thread.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I noticed too. Tried the join() method earlier, and like you said; it does prevent the GUI from updating. My code updates the GUI all the time, simultaneously and I have more than one of these methods running at the same time.

Comment: button.setEnabled(false); You also probably need to add "final" to the line where button is first instantiated.

Comment: In that case you can rely on [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater`](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Disable the button right before starting the thread. In the thread, at the end, post an event that would re-enable the button (using invokeLater).

You may also need a cancel option, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The nice solution for this is to use a [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) to capture all events and stopping them from propagating to any of your UI elements on the panel under the glass pane. Of course while you only have one or two, you can call `setEnabled(false)` on them manually but glass panes give you more flexibility, you'll never have to worry about adding a new element to your UI and forgetting to disable it during background processing.

Probably an overkill for one button though.

Another, unrelated thing you should consider is the use of [`Executor`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) instead of launching threads for background tasks. It results in cleaner and more scalable code.

Comment: There are more than one though. This is just an example from the whole big picture. They will all serve the same purpose and do the same thing, just with different features. I'll look into this though! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    try {
                        clickTest();
                        button.setEnabled(false);//this assume 'button' is final
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Then, modify the `run` method of your `Happiness` class:

```
public void run()
{

 //your processing code here
 ...

 button.setEnabled(true);
 //reference to button can be passed in constructor of Happiness
 // or access using getter, ... This really depend on your implementation.

}
```

Comment: This does not work! :/ The button itself turns grey, but it still reacts to me clicking it.

Comment: oO ... Are you sure ? `setEnabled(false)` should disable all click on the button. What is your OS ?

Comment: Ok I figured it out: you are using a `MouseListener` instead of an `ActionListener`. So you are monitoring mouse click instead of button click. Use `button.addActionListener` instead and it should be fine.

Comment: Win 8.1. But why would that matter :P Yeah... But I am using a Mouse Listener on the button. Could that be the problem? Idk if JButtons have a native 'listen' method.

Comment: Ah yeah woops. Just saw your comment! Thanks I'll try

Comment: `ActionListener` is preferred because the button could be activated by other means too, navigating there with the `TAB` key and pressing return for example.

Comment: I haven't used Swing in years, but shouldn't you follow @Arkadiy 's suggestion and use invokeLater() to re-enable the button after the background task is finished?  I thought that most Swing methods did not like to be invoked in non-swing threads.